# Python random horserace

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function where it takes in a list I give it of my predicted out come of the race and my bet. So for example, i could predict the outcome [1,3,4,2] where horse 1 would be in 1st, horse 3, in 2nd etc... This prediction would be compared to a randomized/ shuffled list a. I have set up a couple of if statements to try and compare both items in each list to each other but it ends up giving me all my placements were correct even if they were not. I am stuck!!!

```
def horseRace(gList,bet):

    import random

    a = [1,2,3,4]
    random.shuffle(a,random.random)
    i = 0
    x = 0
    while i < len(gList):
        if gList[i] == a[0]:
            x = x + 1
        if gList[i] == a[1]:
            x = x + 1
        if gList[i] == a[2]:
            x = x + 1
        if gList[i] == a[3]:
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x
        i = i + 1
    print(x)
    print(a)
    print(gList)
    if x == 4:
        money = bet*2
        print("You guessed 4 position(s) correctly and won $ %d !"%money)
    if x == 0:
        money = 0.00
        print("You guessed no position(s) correctly and won $ %d !"%money)
    if x == 1:
        money = bet
        print("You guessed 1 position(s) correctly and won $ %d !"%money)

    if x == 2:
        money = bet
        print("You guessed 2 position(s) correctly and won $ %d !"%money)

    if x == 3:
        money = bet
        print("You guessed 3 position(s) correctly and won $ %d !"%money)
```

Comment: I think in your `while` loop, you want to compare `gList[i]` to `a[i]`, not to `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc.

Comment: I had already tried that and it still is giving me x = 4 (i.e. all positions are predicted correctly) when i'm only supposed to get x = 1 etc...

Comment: look up `elif`.  I would also suggest walking through this code with pencil and paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `while` loop should look more like this

```
  while i < len(gList):
        if gList[i] == a[i]:
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x
        i = i + 1
```

That way, you're comparing the value in cell position `i` in `gList` to the value in the *same* cell position in `a`. Right now, your code essentially says to add one to `x` as long as the value `gList[i]` is equal to any of:

`a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`, `a[4]`

which of course it wil be

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a for loop to count the number of correct guess. Assuming `gList` and `a` are the same size:

```
for (gList_i, a_i) in zip(gList, a):
    if g_List_i == a_i:
        x += 1
```

Also, maybe a function for the message, that would take the number of positions guessed correctly as an input.

```
def win_message(nwins):
    if nwins == 0:
        money = 0
    elif nwins == 4:
        money = 2*bet
    else: # For nwins equals 2 or 3
        money = bet

    if nwins > 1:
        plural = "s"
    else:
        plural = ""
    print("You guessed %d position%s correctly and won $ %d !" % (nwins, plural, money))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in more Pythonic way, and count the number of correct guess in one line:

```
nCorrect = len(filter(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], zip(randomized,gList)))
```

Here is the full code, I'll explain in the bottom:

```
import random
def horseRace(gList,bet):
    randomized = [1,2,3,4]
    random.shuffle(randomized,random.random)
    nCorrect = len(filter(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], zip(randomized,gList)))

    def getResult(bet,nCorrect):
        if nCorrect==0:
            return 0
        elif nCorrect==4:
            return 2*bet
        else:
            return bet

    outcome = getResult(bet,nCorrect)

    print 'Randomized order: ' + randomized
    print 'Your guess: ' + bet
    print 'You guessed %d position(s) correctly and won $%d!' % (nCorrect,outcome)
```

You should change the `getResult` method depending on how you want to calculate your outcome.

I'll explain this line:

```
nCorrect = len(filter(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], zip(randomized,gList)))
```

So, first, it'll combine the `randomized` and `gList` into a list of tuples:

```
gList = [1,2,3,4]
randomized = [1,3,2,4]
print zip(randomized,gList)
    [(1,1), (2,3), (3,2), (4,4)]
```

Then the `filter` will take only elements that match the condition. In this case the condition is that the first element of the tuple equals the second element of the tuple (`x[0]==x[1]`)

```
print filter(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], zip(randomized,gList))
[(1,1), (4,4)]
```

Then we return the length of the array, which is the number of correct guess.